# What is the area of the small circle?

Tags: geometry

The length of the side of the square is 8 m

[image: area of a small circle (solved)]

Comment: Have you have an thoughts yourself? Please edit them into the question

Comment: Here is a hint: $(4+r)^2=4^2+(4-r)^2.$

Comment: See "The Kiss Precise" ... note: a straight line is considered a circle with curvature $0$.  https://maths.ac-noumea.nc/polyhedr/packing_kiss/kiss.htm  Soddy calls the curvature of a circle the **bend** of the circle, it scans better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $(4+r)^2=(4-r)^2+4^2$ by drawing a right triangle.   Thus $r=1$.  Thus the area is $\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a right-angled triangle with vertices at the centre of the big square, the small circle and on one of the centres of the big semi-circles. Let r be the radius of the small circle. What do you see?

Answer (score 0):

Assume the radius of smaller circle to be $r$ then it is quite easy to see that $(4+r)^2=4^2+(4-r)^2$ using pythgoras as the triangle formed by joining point of contact of semi circles, centre of smaller circle and mid point of side $BC$ is a right angled triangle